# How to disable Picture in Picture mode on Wordpress HTML5 video

Tags: html, video, browser, elementor, picture-in-picture

Hello dear community members!

I have set the video background to the Elementor section.

Problem: when viewing the page through Firefox (from a computer) and the iphone browser, a context menu appears that allows to view the video in a separate window (“picture in picture”).
This feature destroys the whole idea if i were thinking of a video page design with complementary elements on top of the video. If you click on the picture-in-picture context menu, the video from the Elementor section disappears, leaving the entire section empty. I do not want the user to be able to do this on the video page (accidentally or intentionally).

I ask you to suggest a possible solution to this problem in order to exclude any interference from browsers to the video. How do I turn off Picture-in-Picture for a video element?

Example: [section with video background](https://ibb.co/HxgTCRr) / [picture-in-picture section](https://ibb.co/y6K39Pp)

I have found several troubleshooting approaches, but there is not enough technical knowledge to understand how to implement them:

1. About using the [disablePictureInPicture](https://w3c.github.io/picture-in-picture/#disable-pip) attributes.
2. Apple [avpictureinpicturecontroller](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avpictureinpicturecontroller)

Answer (score 0):

```
<video controls disablePictureInPicture controlsList="nodownload">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

And if you want to achieve it through JavaScript

```
<video id="vid" controls muted>
<source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">
</video>
<script>
vid=document.getElementById("vid")
vid.disablePictureInPicture = true
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Wasted a good one hour today trying to figure out why Firefox keeps showing that PiP button for my website background video... The answer is that your video should be less than 45 seconds long. There is a `media.videocontrols.picture-in-picture.video-toggle.min-video-secs` config value which is set to 45 by default. So your video have to be lass than 45 seconds, no other way.